# Why typescript allow to extend function with new property

Tags: typescript

When typescript infer function type on it's own (look at `sampleFunc1`) it allows me to extend it with new prop, but when I explicitly set function type or function is returned from other function (`sampleFunc2` and `returnedSampleFunc`) this functionality is blocked. In other words, for all cases function type should be `() => number` but only for first one typescript allows to extend it, why?

```
const sampleFunc1 = () => { return 1 }   
const sampleFunc2: () => number = () => { return 1 }
const returnFunc = (func: () => number) => func
const returnedSampleFunc = returnFunc(sampleFunc1)

// sampleFunc1.Test = "test" // it works
// sampleFunc2.Test = "test" // Property 'Test' does not exist on type '() => number'
// returnedSampleFunc.Test = "test" // Property 'Test' does not exist on type '() => number'
```

In example below we can see that for object types, extending is not allowed at all. Why then allow it for functions?

```
const obj1 = {a: 1, b: "test"}
const obj2: {a: number, b: string} = {a: 1, b: "test"}

// obj1.Test = "test" // Property 'Test' does not exist on type '{ a: number; b: string; }'
// obj2.Test = "test" // Property 'Test' does not exist on type '{ a: number; b: string; }'
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/AQ4YwewOwZwF2DAhgWwA4BsCmAxArlGAIzAC8wAFAJRkB8wA3sAE5Zx7NTAkC%20oAUKHDR4iVJlwEwAJgBclGqXpQ8KAEZZmZBXUYs2HLr0GhIsBK3ad8hbRQBmU%20dV0r1mxfUeETIM6MtDLAATAGVxbBswbUDrKQpkdEipIip%20X2AAekyxJMlCIgA6ABUsUXIAIjgyuAqsnIBLBAB3CGYAaxgM7NyJKOkSmu0qmrqegAVmCDRNOABPYAByUvhF4GCIMuAoCAQsAA8G0WhgeZmllyVt1Q1mRe6c2KgQ8LyowfLgEfgxnMnp2YLZY1NYbLY7PaHY5cM5YC6ea7uO7pDL%20BAQNQAKxI5AYSHkRAANMA1PJvrUeKiROisXJGPjEbdiaTEHBmA0oABzPi4hlEklk6o-SkPYAY7EfBCVIW1erAf4zZjzJYrOCgzYwba7YAHI7omFzc6LJgMty3ADcAtZ7K5lp49yEPXFA1Vwxlv3lU0VyuBq3WGq1kL1YoNRpN8jNmktLPgNs5dsWQA)

Comment: Function declarations (including arrow functions assigned to variables) are given the privilege to be modified later on in the program. Hover over `sampleFunc1` and you'll see the inferred type (which includes a `Test` property). Your other examples do not work since `() => number` does not allow extra properties.

Comment: This is [a documented feature of the language](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-1.html#properties-declarations-on-functions).  Does that fully answer your question?  If so I will write up an answer (or maybe @pink will and hopefully they link to the docs).  If not, what am I missing?

Comment: @jcalz yep, I think that's answers my question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Expando properties](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Expando) on functions is a documented feature of TypeScript implemented in [microsoft/TypeScript#26368](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/26368) and [released with TypeScript 3.1](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-1.html#properties-declarations-on-functions).  This was introduced to fix the feature request [microsoft/TypeScript#15868](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/15868) to allow for this common JavaScript pattern to be supported in TypeScript.

Before this, it was difficult to add an object to a function like

```
function foo() { }
foo.bar = true; // error!
```

You had to either refactor to use a [`namespace`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/namespaces.html#handbook-content)

```
function foo() { }
namespace foo { export let bar = true };
```

or you had to use something like [`Object.assign()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign) to sneak the extra property in there:

```
const foo = Object.assign(function foo() { }, { bar: true });
```

And neither refactoring was particularly ergonomic for people migrating JavaScript to TypeScript.

---

This isn't supported for objects because it's much easier to add an extra property to an [initializer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer):

```
const foo = {
    baz: "abc",
    bar: true
}
```

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/DYUwLgBAZgXBDeEAUBKOA3A9gSwCYG4IAjAQwCc4jNNQSA7CAX3wFgAodukgWxAGcADiQDGICAFESfAJ4J2EBdACudYWGyYGUaqgRN5i7ZgB0pMhAC8EMGSUhWbRdGqnyBhVEvPMDxu048-EKiEAAS5Lgg5vDuyqrqmt66iH6Oily8giJiRnogAB4CmGSQoJBmXjZ2TA5OnlZGvv5sGUHZEADy0bHCmnyQuVYdRABWIGrGUnzYAOZ0SFAqahpaOih6jAA0emZwVWKMKLWGXo3sqQGZwWIAcphgACoAFiAAyoFyaQo9fQPUXjEvk5iCQAF5wABEJCIwghm1iTl21lsIFiqUYQA)