# Strange behavior of the function properties and control flow analysis

Tags: typescript

The compiler should not allow such a function to be assigned to a `fn` variable. Why is there no wrong type error in this code?

```
type FN = (() => void) & { someValue: number }

const fn: FN = () => {}

if (false) {
    fn.someValue = 3
}

const test = fn.someValue;
      //^? const test: number
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/FAFwngDgpgBAYgORgXhgCjQShQPhgNwHsBLAE2wDIYBvGAZ0IFsoA1AQwBsBXKALhgB2XRgCMoAJxgBfYMADGhAXRAwAZgP6IU6bMjzUZwYqvSrOdKNmrAYttQIB0DZu26xUAZmCGFSlSChlbXUnJlZOHgBuYABIWwB6eIA9AH4gA).

I expect to receive a type error when assigning to a `fn` variable.
Thanks.

Comment: There is no way to initialize a function with props from the beginning without going through the prototype or class, so typescript does not consider it an error.

Comment: @TachibanaShin - That sounds plausible, though unfortunate. Can you point to documentation of that? There's always `const fn: FN = Object.assign(() => {}, {someValue: 42});` [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76016437/157247) suggests TypeScript just lets you add expandos, but doesn't seem to quite cover this case of a declared property...

Comment: Interestingly, [there's an error if you never assign `somevalue`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAYgclAvFA3gKCpqAKAlALigDcB7ASwBMBuDLAZxIFsIA1AQwBsBXCQgOy6MARhABONAL400AYxJ86wKADM+heEhy4kAPlRS0s+YqjAIJ5KoB0DZu24QaASEwB6VwD0A-EA). Is your question why the `if (false)` didn't make TypeScript understand the property never gets assigned?

Comment: @ T.J. Crowder
Yes. It seems strange to me that it is so easy to get a potential error in runtime. This doesn't work with regular objects. But with functions it works. And it's strange.

Comment: Can you change `if (false)` to something like `if (Math.random()<0.5)`?  The compiler will say that the body of `if (false)` is unreachable, and any error you get invalidates a lot of other checking.  It's more noteworthy that TS will not complain if `fn.someValue` is *potentially* uninitialized, not when the whole code block doing the initialization is literally unreachable.  If you do this, I think I might file a TS bug report about it, since it seems like at least a limitation in the language and I don't see an existing relevant issue.